# Have I opened myself to a hack from posting terminal output here?

Tags: security, privacy, hacking, vulnerability, pastebin

So, yesterday I posed [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003135/repeating-unknown-system-notification-sound-kernel-4-4-0-108) where I supplied two `dmesg | tail` outputs, plus `uname -a` and `ls -a /boot`. It disclosed my system time and my username, (plus my VPN provider and other software).

I was searching for hits on some of the `dmesg` output, and found a [pastebin page](https://pastebin.com/Fb21j3DA) with all of the code I put into that post. Nothing else, just the code from my post.

It was put there by a guest and at the time of writing it had *63 unique views*. Are you kidding??

I wasn't expecting any of that, especially since no-one has responded to the question on the forum.

Frankly, I'm a little freaked out. :/

I searched for "askubuntu pastebin" but didn't come up with anything satisfactory.

My worst fears are that I have somehow advertised a vulnerability and I'm identifiable and there's a group of hackers coming to get me.

What is really going on, please? Or do I really have to worry now?

Thanks

Comment: There are any number of sites that scrape SE posts. Plus I'd bet that if your system were publicly accessible it be getting far more than 63 unique hits each day just from random scanning on the internet.

Comment: I don’t find any sensitive information in your question (and the PasteBin page). I wouldn’t worry about resharing that.

Comment: okay, thanks both of you. Melebius, I had hoped the info was safe before I posted it (but got nervous...), but I really am surprised at the scraping, muru. What do these sites gain from it?